# Escape sequence for wmic command

Tags: c++, escaping, special-characters, wmic

I used the below wmic command in my c++ code to install an application in my remote system

**`/node:192.xxx.xxx.xx /user:"Administrator" /password:"Murali678"" product call install true,"","\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\admin$\Murali\Myapplication.msi"`**

But i got an error message

```
, - Alias not found.
```

So i tried to add an escape sequence for my remote machine's password in the command. So i did the below.

1)
**`/node:192.xxx.xxx.xx /user:"Administrator" /password:"Murali678\"" product call install true,"","\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\admin$\Murali\Myapplication.msi"`**

**Output**

```
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.
```

2)
**`/node:192.xxx.xxx.xx /user:"Administrator" /password:"Murali678^"" product call install true,"","\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\admin$\Murali\Myapplication.msi"`**

**Output**

```
, - Alias not found.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would it work if you omit the `/password` parameter at all and and then enter the user's password when prompted?

Comment: I want to execute the command in c++ i can't do as you said. I must specify the password along with the command

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add appropriate tag(s), at least `c++`. Add an example of your `wmic` command which is running from pure `cmd` and add `c++` [mcve]

Comment: Ok josefz i will edit the question